# Avoiding Arrow Pattern with C# Pattern Matching

Tags: c#, object-oriented, .net-core

I have started to use C# 7's type based [pattern matching](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching). A method that only manages a single pattern-based result looks very clean and is easy to reason about.

However, once a second pattern-based result that depends on the first pattern-based result creates an arrow anti-pattern, and will only get worse with n-results that depend on each other.

Here is an simplified example that demonstrates the arrow pattern:

```
public Result<bool> ValidateSomething(string strId)
{
    var id = Guid.Parse(strId);
    Result<Something> fetchSomethingResult = new SomethingDao.FetchSomething(id);
    switch (fetchSomethingResult)
    {
        case ValueResult<Something> successfulSomethingResult:
            Result<Related> fetchRelatedFieldsResult = new RelatedDao.FetchRelatedFields(successfulSomethingResult.Value.RelatedId);
    
            switch (fetchRelatedFieldsResult)
            {
                case ValueResult<Related> successfulFieldValueResult:
                    var isValid = successfulSomethingResult.Value.ComparableVal <= successfulFieldValueResult.Value.RelatedComparableVal;
                    return new ValueResult<bool>(isValid);
                case ValueNotFoundResult<Related> _:
                    return new ValueNotFoundResult<bool>();
                case ErrorResult<Related> errorResult:
                    return new ErrorResult<bool>(errorResult.ResultException);
                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException("Unexpected Result Type Received.");
            }
        case ValueNotFoundResult<Something> notFoundResult:
            return new ValueNotFoundResult<bool>();
        case ErrorResult<Something> errorResult:
            return new ErrorResult<bool>(errorResult.ResultException);
        default:
            throw new NotImplementedException("Unexpected Result Type Received.");
    }
}
```

For reference, these are the definitions for the `Result` classes:

```
public abstract class Result<T>
{

}

public class ValueResult<T> : Result<T>
{
    public ValueResult()
    {
    }

    public ValueResult(T inValue)
    {
        Value = inValue;
    }

    public T Value { get; set; }
}

public class ValueNotFoundResult<T> : Result<T>
{
    public ValueNotFoundResult()
    {
    }
}

public class ErrorResult<T> : Result<T>
{
    public Exception ResultException { get; set; }

    public ErrorResult()
    {
    }

    public ErrorResult(Exception resultException)
    {
        ResultException = resultException;
    }
}
```

What options are there to handle this type of code better? What suggestions do you have for the previous examples? How do I avoid the arrow anti-pattern with pattern-based results?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Unfortunately this question does not match what this site is about. Please re-read the Help center page [_What topics can I ask about here?_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) - specifically the third question. Reviewers need more than hypothetical/stub code. For more information, see [this meta post](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3652/120114).